# Angular 2 Material: can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'md-radio-button'

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-material

I am running an example of radio buttons from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio), I have made sure to follow all the [instruction](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), except for the appendix, since I have no 
such file (my app was created cli).

After including the html template my app won't render and in the console I have an error:

> can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of
>   'md-radio-button

My ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SlidesService } from 'app/slides/slides.service';
import { Slide } from 'app/slides/slide';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.css']
})
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _slidesService: SlidesService) { }
  slides: Slide[];
  currSlide: Slide;
  favoriteSeason: string;

  seasons = [
    'Winter',
    'Spring',
    'Summer',
    'Autumn',
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
    this._slidesService.getSlides()
      .subscribe(slides => {
        this.slides = slides
        this.currSlide = slides[0];

      },
      error => console.log(<any>error));
  }

}
```

my html file:

```
<div class="well well-lg" *ngIf='slides && slides.length'>
  <img [src]='slides[0].imageUrl'>
  <h1>{{currSlide.SongTitle}}</h1>
  <md-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
    <md-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
      {{season}}
    </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
</div>
```

AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SlidesComponent } from './slides/slides.component';
import { SlidesService } from './slides/slides.service';
import { QuestionComponent } from './question/question.component';
import { MdButtonModule, MdCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SlidesComponent,
    QuestionComponent
  ],
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCheckboxModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot(),
    CarouselModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [SlidesService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'd appreciate suggestions to resolve this issues.

Comment: `MdButtonModule` (actually **all** of your material modules) should be imported in either `AppModule`, or whatever containing module this component lives in In that modules `imports` array. **NOT** In the component. All the `import` statement here does is imports the "sybmol". You are not actually consuming it anywhere, nor is it possible to do so in a component.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I was not sure about that, so I actually imported the symbols both in that component ts file and both in the AppModule (and the imports array). After your comment I tried removing the imports from the component and left it only in the AppModule - but I get the same error

Comment: @belgi is it possible for you to add your appModule definition? Looks like you are missing to add some declaration out there like CommonModule or FormModule

Comment: Yeah. Missing `MdRadioModule` as mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

Since this seems not to have come to a conclusion, I thought I'd provide answer, from which **ALL** the credit goes to Neil Lunn!

As Sajeetharan's answer works with `MaterialModule` imported, but as Neil Lunn stated:

> You should only import the "required" modules

since otherwise

> this will result in a larger bundle for builds.

So this is simply solved by importing `MdRadioModule` to your app module and adding it to the `imports` array:

```ts
import { MdRadioModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
  ....
  MdRadioModule, 
  ....
],
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to import the `MdRadioModule` in appModule, and also paste it under `imports`.